# How to wait for code executing in Android? Runnable failed for me

Tags: android, wait, runnable

I want to wait inside my while loop for like 1 second **each time it is inside the loop.**

I tryed with Runnable:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        int i=0;

        while(i<10){
            if(i%2 ==0){

                myTextView.setText("true");
            }
            else{

                myTextView.setText("false");
            }

            i++;
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```

If i ran this code i got a blank display for minutes and then a crash.

Logcat:

```
 ActivityManager      Reason: keyDispacthingTimeot
```

What is the problem?
I would like to make this as simple as it can be...

Please help!

Comment: You should not change your UI in any other thread except UI thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to make sthg very simple, then just use

```
Thread.currentThread();
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

**Note**: as Adeel said, do not sleep in a UI thread =)

**EDIT**: you should implement sthg like this:

I think you want to use a `asyncTask`, and `publishprogress` each one sec. So make your own `asyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>`, and on the `doInbackground` method:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    int i=0;

    while(i<10){
        Thread.currentThread();
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }

        publishProgress(new Integer(i));

        i++;
    }
}
```

Then implement the `onProgressUpdate` method which runs on UI thread, and:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     int i = progress[0].intValue();
     if(i%2 ==0){
            myTextView.setText("true");
        }
        else{

            myTextView.setText("false");
        }
 }
```

Here is the doc about [asynctasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this in the while loop

> Thread.sleep(1000);